# How can I display addition operation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 "render": function(data, type, row) {
     var html = data.amount + data.interes;
     return html;
  }
```

This image is not correct because when I display It will become 1005, 10040. The correct addition is 105 and 140 this is want to display.

[image]

Comment: We've to know the values you're calculating with.

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor.

Comment: @Teemu i don't know  why display like this 1005, the correct is 105 I've used javascript operator `+` example `data1 + data2` like this.

Comment: Yes, but what values `data1` and `data2` have?

Comment: @Teemu `data1 = 100  + data2 = 5' but the result is 1005, the correct result is `105`, what wrong of my code ?

Comment: Seems you are just concatenating two string values, try converting them to number `parseInt(data.amount) + parseInt(data.interes)`.

Comment: @MakuriDavid OK, Quentin has found a good post that answers your question.